# How to locate Titanium mobile sdk in titanium studio?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I have installed titanium studio in my pc.i am succesfully build the jdk path and android sdk path.but when i start titanium studio and go to window--preferences--titaniumstudio--titanium and locate C:\Users\chaiti\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobile-sdk\win32\android it shows Could not locate a Titanium Mobile SDK at the given path.because of this when i create new project and run then it shows the following error:

```
[INFO] logfile = C:\Users\chaiti\My Documents\Titanium Studio Workspace\Hello\build.log
[INFO] Building Hello for Android ... one moment
[ERROR] Exception occured while building Android project:
[ERROR] Traceback (most recent call last):
[ERROR]   File "C:\Users\chaiti\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\2.0.1.GA2\android\builder.py", line 2119, in <module>
[ERROR]     s.build_and_run(False, avd_id, debugger_host=debugger_host)
[ERROR]   File "C:\Users\chaiti\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\2.0.1.GA2\android\builder.py", line 1735, in build_and_run
[ERROR]     run.run([self.sdk.get_adb(), "start-server"], True, ignore_output=True)
[ERROR]   File "C:\Users\chaiti\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\2.0.1.GA2\android\run.py", line 30, in run
[ERROR]     print "[DEBUG] %s" % (subprocess.list2cmdline(args))
[ERROR]   File "C:\Users\chaiti\AppData\Local\Titanium Studio\plugins\com.appcelerator.titanium.python.win32_1.0.0.1331647813\python\lib\subprocess.py", line 503, in list2cmdline
[ERROR]     needquote = (" " in arg) or ("\t" in arg) or arg == ""
[ERROR] TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting path for window--preferences--titanium studio--titanium as

> C:\Users\chaiti\AppData\Roaming\Titanium

only.

Answer (score 1):

1. Window->Preferences-Titanium Studio-Titanium, set the Titanium SDK Home to
   `C:\Users\SIXBUBLE\AppData\Roaming\Titanium`
2. Follow [this thread](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/129786/could-not-locate-a-titanium-desktop-sdk-at-the-given-path)

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem.
But, If I just locate to C:\Users\SIXBUBLE\AppData\Roaming\Titanium, I get this :
Titanium SDK Home] The Desktop-SDK root path 'C:\Users\SIXBUBLE\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\sdk\win32' is not a directory